# Strange session behaviour in Google Chrome for Twitter OAuth

Tags: google-chrome, session, twitter, twitter-oauth

for some strange reason in Google Chrome one of my scripts is having serious problems. I'm setting up a page that requires twitter/facebook connections. Basically what you are doing is:

1. visit page (Facebook+Twitter class are started, some session settings are being set etc)
2. Click the connect button for one of the networks
3. fill in your connection details
4. sign up at our website (clicking submit).

Now everything works perfectly in IE/Firefox/Safari, however Chrome is doing some really crazy stuff. I would like to ask you to visit this page:

**Not Important Anymore**

Most likely in Firefox/IE/Safari it will just display an empty var_dump() of the $_SESSION variable. At first this is what it does in Chrome aswel, BUT! If you refresh the page once in Firefox/IE/Safari the session is still empty, but in Chrome it is showing some keys already.

I have absolutely no clue where these keys come from.. this is the content of viewsessions.php:

```
session_start();
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_SESSION);

if(isset($_GET['u'])) {
    unset($_SESSION);   
}
```

As far as I know there cannot happen anything else but the above and Firefox/IE/Safari are showing the right behaviour.

It wouldn't be a big problem if everything was working fine, but al the 'requestoken_XXXX' session keys belong to the Twitter OAuth.. and because the requesttoken is refreshed on everypage the Authentication redirect to my website can not find a matching token and thus not validate the authentication.

Can anyone see what is happening? Is some page being called in the back? Is this some Chrome related issue that is known? I really don't have any clues left what this could be..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved..

For some reason this file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    Options -Indexes

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    # Bestaande bestanden of mappen uitsluiten
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1 [L] 

    RewriteRule ^start/$ login.php [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^logout/$ logout.php [L,QSA]
    RewriteRule ^timeline/$ timeline.php [L,QSA]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Did some request to index.php (I guess...), seems a bit odd because I have stated that if it's an existing file or directory it should just open the file: `RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1 [L]` and I also flagged it as the last rule to follow.

Removing this last RewriteRule solved the problem. Still not sure why Chrome overrules the [L] parameter.. if anyone could explain it, that would be awesome.